# I can't create dashboard in thingsboard in my Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, thingsboard

I installed Thingsboard on Raspberry Pi 3 b+ and Use Postgres as dtb. Installing the program well. I just test by sending data to Thingsboard. It's work!
 When I click dashboard tab. Red massage appear at top left

"GET: /api/customer/211f0000-df24-1412-8080-808080808080/shortInfo 404: "

[GET Message Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3rG8.png)
                                                        '

When I try to create Thingsboard. All widget are disappear with message
 "Access Forbidden You haven't access rights to this location! Try to sign in with different user if you still wish to gain access to this location."
Anyone know what happen and how to fix it. Thanks

[Access Forbidden Message Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRJH3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just had that same problem on my raspberry pi 3b+. I solved it by changing all the assets and devices that were used on the dashboard do the same customer, in my case, public.